# Twitter API search keywords in a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, twitter

Is there a way to do that from official API? I'm trying to caching tweets in a list that contain some keywords, so it won't be flushed by Twitter's default 7 days caching. I would prefer to query all the old tweets and store it to some database, but I can live with just caching all the tweets from now on. How do I approach it? I would also appreciate some ruby library recommendations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported on current api, so I'm just loop through the tweet.text and match it with a regex. Query the api every 10 mins with a cron job. It works!